# Do ASP.NET or the Windows Event Log Rate Limit?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, exception, logging, event-log

I'm testing out some error handling in ASP.NET MVC, but my exceptions only get logged around once per minute (at least that's what it looks like).

I have CustomErrors turned on:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Home/Error">
```

and I removed the global filter for the HandleErrorAttribute.  My Controller and action do not have the HandleError attribute.

I have a controller actions that throws an exception like this:

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    var random = new Random();

    throw new Exception(random.Next().ToString());
}
```

But if I go to this page multiple times (can't just refresh because it redirects) I only see 1 event in the Windows Event Log every minute.  I tried hitting the same page from another browser and that exception didn't get logged either.

Is there some sort of rate limiting done by ASP.NET or the Windows Event Log?

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but I'd recommend [`Install-Package Elmah.MVC`](http://nuget.org/packages/Elmah.MVC)

Comment: Yeah, I've already pitched that here.  For now, I'm seeing if we can remove custom event logging code in favor of letting the framework and windows log exceptions automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Rate limiting is done by ASP.NET according to the attribute minInterval of the system.web/healthMonitoring/rules/add and the system.web/healthMonitoring/profiles/add elements in the Web.config

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/23t1tcty%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

In order to log all errors you can add this to the Web.config ([source](https://leansentry.zendesk.com/entries/23584078-How-do-I-enable-ASP-NET-detailed-error-tracking-)):

```
<system.web>
    <healthMonitoring>
        <rules>
            <!-- Make sure all errors are logged to the EventLogProvider ("Default" profile only allows 1 error per minute) -->
            <remove name="All Errors Default" />
            <add name="All Errors Default" eventName="All Errors" profile="Critical" provider="EventLogProvider" />
        </rules>
    </healthMonitoring>
</system.web>
```